WebRTC ICE and SDP Exchange Successful, but PeerConnection Stuck in new state
I am building a voice/video calling app on Android using WebRTC, where SDP and ICE candidates are exchanged through a WebSocket server. The flow of SDP and ICE candidates between two users (A and B) looks correct in the WebSocket logs, but the connection doesn't seem to fully establish.
Websocket Log
User = A Send User B =>> offer of SDP
User = A Send User B =>> offer of ICE
User = A Send User B =>> offer of ICE
User = A Send User B =>> offer of ICE
User = A Send User B =>> offer of ICE
User = A Send User B =>> offer of ICE
User = A Send User B =>> offer of ICE
User = A Send User B =>> offer of ICE
User = A Send User B =>> offer of ICE
User = B Send User A =>> answer of SDP
User = B Send User A =>> answer of ICE
User = B Send User A =>> answer of ICE
User = B Send User A =>> answer of ICE
User = B Send User A =>> answer of ICE
User = B Send User A =>> answer of ICE
User = B Send User A =>> answer of ICE
User = B Send User A =>> answer of ICE
User = B Send User A =>> answer of ICE

However, in the Android logs, the connection state doesn’t progress as expected after the ICE exchange completes. The connection remains in the following states indefinitely:
Log.d(TAG, "Connection State: " + peerConnection.connectionState());  // Shows "New"
Log.d(TAG, "ICE Connection State: " + peerConnection.iceConnectionState());  // Shows "Checking"
Log.d(TAG, "ICE Gathering State: " + peerConnection.iceGatheringState());  // Shows "Gathering"

My Call Fragment.
public class Video_Voice_Call_Fragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "Call_Fragment";
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public static final int VIDEO_RESOLUTION_WIDTH = 1280;
    public static final int VIDEO_RESOLUTION_HEIGHT = 720;
    public static final int FPS = 30;

    private EglBase rootEglBase;
    private PeerConnectionFactory peerConnectionFactory;
    private VideoCapturer videoCapturer;
    private VideoSource videoSource;
    private VideoTrack localVideoTrack;
    private AudioTrack localAudioTrack;
    private SurfaceViewRenderer localVideoView;
    private SurfaceTextureHelper surfaceTextureHelper;
    private SurfaceViewRenderer remoteVideoView;
    private ImageButton greenCallButton;
    private ImageButton redCallButton;
    private MediaStream localMediaStream;
    OkHttpClient client;
    PeerConnection peerConnection,peerConnectionRemote;
    private String FCMToken_Other;

    TextView CallStatus;
    ImageView UserImage;
    boolean isCaller = true;
    boolean isVoiceCall;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_voice_call, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        localVideoView = view.findViewById(R.id.call_remoteSurfaceView);
        greenCallButton = view.findViewById(R.id.call_connect);
        redCallButton = view.findViewById(R.id.call_disconnect);
        if (isCaller){
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) redCallButton.getLayoutParams();
            params.startToStart = ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID;
            params.setMarginEnd(0);
            redCallButton.setLayoutParams(params);
            greenCallButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        UserImage = view.findViewById(R.id.call_UserImage);
        CallStatus = view.findViewById(R.id.call_Status);
        TextView CallName = view.findViewById(R.id.call_callerName);

        isVoiceCall = getArguments().getBoolean("VoiceCall");
        String ImagePath = getArguments().getString("image");
        String Name = getArguments().getString("name");
        FCMToken_Other = getArguments().getString("fcm");
        int OtherUserID = getArguments().getInt("OtherID");
        Session.setOtherUserID(OtherUserID);
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(ImagePath).into(UserImage);
        CallStatus.setText("Connecting...");
        CallName.setText(Name);

        client = new OkHttpClient();

       
        initializePeerConnectionFactory(isVoiceCall);
        setupLocalTracks(isVoiceCall);
        setupUI(view);
        startCall(isVoiceCall);
    }


    
    private void initializePeerConnectionFactory(boolean isVoiceCall) {
        // Initialize EGL context for rendering
        rootEglBase = EglBase.create();

        // Initialize PeerConnectionFactory
        PeerConnectionFactory.initialize(PeerConnectionFactory.InitializationOptions.builder(requireContext())
                .setEnableInternalTracer(true)
                .createInitializationOptions());

        PeerConnectionFactory.Options options = new PeerConnectionFactory.Options();
        PeerConnectionFactory.Builder builder = PeerConnectionFactory.builder();
        options.networkIgnoreMask = 16;
        options.disableNetworkMonitor = true;

        if (!isVoiceCall){
            //Video Call
            DefaultVideoEncoderFactory videoEncoderFactory = new DefaultVideoEncoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(),true,true);
            DefaultVideoDecoderFactory videoDecoderFactory = new DefaultVideoDecoderFactory(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
            builder.setVideoEncoderFactory(videoEncoderFactory);
            builder.setVideoDecoderFactory(videoDecoderFactory);
            //Set EGL context
            localVideoView.init(rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext(), null);
            localVideoView.setMirror(true);
            getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }

        peerConnectionFactory = builder.setOptions(options).createPeerConnectionFactory();

    }

    private void setupLocalTracks(boolean isVoiceCall) {
        localMediaStream = peerConnectionFactory.createLocalMediaStream("local_stream");
        if (!isVoiceCall){
            // Create video capturer
            videoCapturer = createVideoCapturer();
            // Create video source
            videoSource = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoSource(false);
            localVideoTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createVideoTrack("local_video", videoSource);
            surfaceTextureHelper = SurfaceTextureHelper.create("SurfaceHelper",rootEglBase.getEglBaseContext());
            videoCapturer.initialize(surfaceTextureHelper,getActivity(),videoSource.getCapturerObserver());
            if (videoCapturer!=null){
                videoCapturer.startCapture(VIDEO_RESOLUTION_WIDTH,VIDEO_RESOLUTION_HEIGHT,FPS);
                localVideoTrack.addSink(localVideoView);
            }
            localMediaStream.addTrack(localVideoTrack);
        }



        // Create audio source and track
        AudioSource audioSource = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(new MediaConstraints());
        localAudioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack("local_audio", audioSource);
        // Create local media stream
        localMediaStream.addTrack(localAudioTrack);

    }

    private VideoCapturer createVideoCapturer() {
        VideoCapturer videoCapturer;
        CameraEnumerator enumerator = new Camera2Enumerator(requireContext());

        final String[] deviceNames = enumerator.getDeviceNames();

        // Find front facing camera
        for (String deviceName : deviceNames) {
            if (enumerator.isFrontFacing(deviceName)) {
                videoCapturer = enumerator.createCapturer(deviceName, null);
                if (videoCapturer != null) {
                    return videoCapturer;
                }
            }
        }

        // Front facing camera not found, use the first available
        if (deviceNames.length > 0) {
            return enumerator.createCapturer(deviceNames[0], null);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

   



    private void startCall(boolean isVoiceCall) {
      
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting call...");

        // Create an offer and set local description
        peerConnection = InitializePeerConnection();
       
        if (!isVoiceCall){
            peerConnection.addTrack(localVideoTrack);
        }

        peerConnection.addTrack(localAudioTrack);

        peerConnection.createOffer(new SimpleSdpObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreateSuccess: " + sessionDescription.description);

                Websocket.connectWebSocket(new WebSocketCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuccess() {
                        //Websocket Connected
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionSuccess: Websocket Connected");
                        String message = generateJSON(sessionDescription.description,true,"offer");
                        peerConnection.setLocalDescription(new SimpleSdpObserver(), sessionDescription);
                        Websocket.sendMessage(message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailure(String message) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailure: Message = "+message);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionClosed(String reason) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionClosed: Reason = "+reason);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionsMessage(String message) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionsMessage: Message = "+message);
                        // Here User will receive the message from the websocket
                        try{
                            JSONObject socketMessage = new JSONObject(message);
                            String type = socketMessage.getString("type");
                            Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionsMessage: Type = "+type);
                            String sdp_ice_VALUE = null ;
                            if (socketMessage.has("SDP_ICE_info")){
                                sdp_ice_VALUE = socketMessage.getString("SDP_ICE_info");
                            }

                            switch (type) {
                                case "SDP":
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionsMessage: Type SDP");
                                    SessionDescription sessionDescription = new SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER, sdp_ice_VALUE);
                                    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new SdpObserver() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateSuccess: ");
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onSetSuccess() {

                                            Log.d(TAG, "onSetSuccess: Gathering state = " + peerConnection.iceGatheringState());
                                            Log.d(TAG, "onSetSuccess: Connection State = " + peerConnection.iceConnectionState());
                         

                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCreateFailure(String s) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateFailure: " + s);
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onSetFailure(String s) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "onSetFailure: " + s);
                                        }
                                    }, sessionDescription);
                                    //Generate ICE and Send it User B

                                    break;
                                case "Offline":
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionsMessage: OFFLINE");
                                    DefaultExecutorSupplier.getInstance().forMainThreadTasks().execute(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User Is Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            CallStatus.setText("Offline");
                                            closeConnection();
                                        }
                                    });

                                    break;

                                case "ICE":
                                    // Received ICE from server as answer, This is the last step in exchanging info
                                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionsMessage: Message Recevied ICE  = " + type);
                                    addIceCandidates(sdp_ice_VALUE);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onMessage: Error "+e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });

               
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreateFailure(String s) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onCreateFailure: " + s);
            }
        }, new MediaConstraints());
    }

    private PeerConnection InitializePeerConnection(){
        ArrayList<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> STUNList= Arrays.asList(
                "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
                "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
                "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302",
                "stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302",
                "stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302");
        for(String i:STUNList){
            PeerConnection.IceServer.Builder iceServerBuilder = PeerConnection.IceServer.builder(i);
          //iceServerBuilder.setTlsCertPolicy(PeerConnection.TlsCertPolicy.TLS_CERT_POLICY_INSECURE_NO_CHECK);
            iceServerBuilder.setTlsCertPolicy(PeerConnection.TlsCertPolicy.TLS_CERT_POLICY_SECURE);
            PeerConnection.IceServer iceServer =  iceServerBuilder.createIceServer();
            iceServers.add(iceServer);
        }
        PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration rtcConfig = new PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(iceServers);

        PeerConnection.Observer observer = new PeerConnection.Observer() {
            @Override
            public void onSignalingChange(PeerConnection.SignalingState signalingState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSignalingChange: "+signalingState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceConnectionChange(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState iceConnectionState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionChange: "+iceConnectionState);
                if (PeerConnection.IceConnectionState.CONNECTED == iceConnectionState){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionChange: Connection Established");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceConnectionReceivingChange(boolean b) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionReceivingChange: Boolean = "+b);
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceGatheringChange(PeerConnection.IceGatheringState iceGatheringState) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceGatheringChange: "+iceGatheringState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidate: 458 "+Session.getUserID());
                String ice = generateJSON(iceCandidate.toString(),false,"offer");
                Websocket.sendMessage(ice);
            }

            @Override
            public void onIceCandidatesRemoved(IceCandidate[] iceCandidates) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidatesRemoved: "+iceCandidates);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAddStream: "+mediaStream);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRemoveStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onRemoveStream: "+mediaStream);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChannel(DataChannel dataChannel) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChannel: "+dataChannel);
            }

            @Override
            public void onRenegotiationNeeded() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onRenegotiationNeeded: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAddTrack(RtpReceiver rtpReceiver, MediaStream[] mediaStreams) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onAddTrack: "+rtpReceiver+"--- "+mediaStreams);
            }
        };

        return peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig,observer);
        }



    private void endCall() {
        // End the call and release resources
        // Code to end the call goes here
        if (peerConnection!=null){
            Log.d(TAG, "endCall: Connection State ="+peerConnection.connectionState());
            Log.d(TAG, "endCall: Ice Connection State ="+peerConnection.iceConnectionState());
            Log.d(TAG, "endCall: Ice Gathering State ="+peerConnection.iceGatheringState());
        }

    }

  

    private class CustomPeerConnectionObserver implements PeerConnection.Observer {
        @Override
        public void onSignalingChange(PeerConnection.SignalingState signalingState) {
            // Handle signaling state change
            Log.d(TAG, "onSignalingChange: "+signalingState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceConnectionChange(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState iceConnectionState) {
            // Handle ICE connection state change
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionChange: "+iceConnectionState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceConnectionReceivingChange(boolean b) {
            // Handle ICE connection receiving change
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceConnectionReceivingChange: "+b);
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceGatheringChange(PeerConnection.IceGatheringState iceGatheringState) {
            // Handle ICE gathering state change
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceGatheringChange: "+iceGatheringState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate iceCandidate) {
            // Handle ICE candidate
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidate: "+iceCandidate);
        }

        @Override
        public void onIceCandidatesRemoved(IceCandidate[] iceCandidates) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onIceCandidatesRemoved: "+iceCandidates.length);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
            // Handle new stream added
            Log.d(TAG, "onAddStream: "+mediaStream);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoveStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
            // Handle stream removed
            Log.d(TAG, "onRemoveStream: "+mediaStream);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChannel(DataChannel dataChannel) {
            // Handle data channel
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChannel: "+dataChannel);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRenegotiationNeeded() {
            // Handle renegotiation needed
        }

        @Override
        public void onAddTrack(RtpReceiver rtpReceiver, MediaStream[] mediaStreams) {

        }
    }


    // Helper class for handling SDP observer events
    private static class SimpleSdpObserver implements SdpObserver {
        @Override
        public void onCreateSuccess(SessionDescription sessionDescription) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateSuccess: Class Session Description = "+sessionDescription.description);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSetSuccess() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSetSuccess: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateFailure(String s) {}

        @Override
        public void onSetFailure(String s) {}
    }

   

    private void addIceCandidates(String iceCandidates){
        IceCandidate iceCandidateObject = new IceCandidate("sdpMid", 0,iceCandidates);
        // Add the IceCandidate object to the PeerConnection
        peerConnection.addIceCandidate(iceCandidateObject);
    }

    
}

Despite the ICE candidates being exchanged, the connection doesn't transition to a "Connected" state. I've verified that both users are sending and receiving ICE candidates.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with WebRTC on Android? What might prevent the ICE connection from progressing beyond the "Checking" state?
I am using this webrtc library https://github.com/rno/WebRTC
